# Which components for the Simulacrum spell are consumed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, spellcasting-focus, simulacrum

The components of the [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell read as follows

> Components: V, S, M (snow or ice in quantities sufficient to made a life-size copy of the duplicated creature; some hair, fingernail clippings, or other piece of that creature's body placed inside the snow or ice; and powdered ruby worth 1,500 gp, sprinkled over the duplicate and consumed by the spell)

Are the snow/ice and the pieces of the creature's body consumed?

(This question is due to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138810/45088) suggesting that components that are not consumed can be substituted for the arcane focus. An excellent answer would address this as well.)

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47300/are-normal-spell-components-consumed-by-the-spell?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The snow and body parts are not consumed by the casting

... but reusing them after the spell's done might be difficult.

By the text of the spell:

> The duplicate is a creature, partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature.

We know that the snow and bits are around and animate, at least for the duration of the spell. Plus, when the spell ends, the snow becomes water:

> The simulacrum lasts until it drops to 0 hit points, at which point it reverts to snow and melts instantly.

It doesn't explicitly say what happens when it hits the *duration*, but we can infer it'd be about the same thing as it dropping to 0 hit points.

It also doesn't mention what happens to the hair / fingernail clippings - but they'd probably be left behind in the soupy mess.

Finally, if you cast the spell again, the snow + bits are lost:

> If you cast this spell again, any duplicate you created with this spell is instantly destroyed.

Additionally, Spell Components are not consumed unless the [spell explicitly says they are](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/rules-spellcasting) which further backs up that the snow and human-parts remain.

The ruby powder, however, is consumed as it is specifically mentioned as being so in the spell description.

### Can I use a Foci / Spell component pouch in place of the clippings and snow?

I suppose this depends on the reading of the rule - you're turning a big hunk of snow into a fake person, which is then animated by the force of the spell into a walking thing. If you want to substitute a foci for this...you don't actually have a *thing* to animate, so I wouldn't allow it.

A strict reading of the rules, though, doesn't cover this particular case - so you possibly could.

Though there's no way you're fitting a full person's worth of snow into a spell component pouch.